# Possível bug na exibição do contador de perguntas em destaque

Tags: bug

Já faz algum tempo que eu notei esse bug: ao acessar o site, o número indicado de perguntas em destaque está errado, pois indica que há *uma pergunta a mais* do que as que são exibidas. Só que depois de interagir um pouco com o site eu não conseguia mais "reproduzir" o erro, e por isso não postei até hoje.

Hoje, meio que sem querer, eu descobri uma forma de reproduzir (ao menos por aqui):

- Ao acessar o site pela primeira vez, as perguntas são exibidas na "visão principal" em que são ordenadas pelas mais ativas. Nessa visão, já se pode ver a indicação do número de perguntas em destaque:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Porém, ao clicar na aba "em destaque", as perguntas listadas não são condizentes com o número indicado. Isso *possivelmente* ocorreu porque havia outra pergunta em destaque cuja recompensa foi concedida recentemente (mas não tenho certeza disso):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O motivo de eu ter demorado pra perceber como "reproduzir" o bug deve-se ao fato de que eu costumo clicar no botão "Perguntas". Nesse caso, o número de perguntas em destaque é exibido corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Mas, se eu volto a acessar o site pelo link ou clico no logo (pra que a visão principal seja reexibida), o número volta a ser exibido de maneira incorreta.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, já existia uma discussão desse problema: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/contagem-errada-de-perguntas-apresentadas

Comment: Luiz Vieira, de qualquer forma, obrigado pelo reporte. Vou confirmar com o Gabe se esse bug já foi enviado aos desenvolvedores.

Comment: Já conversei a equipe de desenvolvimento, mas a resposta normalmente é "Não consigo reproduzir. Deve ser problema de cache."

Comment: @Gabe Aqui já aconteceu várias vezes. Da próxima vez que ocorrer eu vou tentar testar pra ver se é mesmo um problema de cache. Bom, mesmo assim, valeu pela atenção.

Comment: @LuizVieira Fala comigo, aqui ou no chat, na hora que acontecer de novo, pra ver se eu consigo reproduzir

Comment: @Gabe Pode deixar!